# Batch file with Powershell command quotes

Tags: windows, networking, command-line, powershell, batch

I have created a script to change my `IP` address/mask and `VLAN ID` of an interface but the problem is that in order to change the `VLAN ID`, I need to execute a `PowerShell` command. My variable containing the interface name contains a space, so I need to put it in quotes. The problem is that I need to insert two variables for the same `interfaceName`, one with single quotes for the Powershell command and another for the batch `netsh` command, otherwise, I am getting an error. This is my batch file:

```
:: Configuration Variables
set ifName='Ethernet 2'
set connectionName="Ethernet 2"
set ipAddress=10.88.167.27
set subnetMask=255.255.255.240
set vlanID=100

:: set defaultGateway=x.x.x.x
:: set primaryDNS=x.x.x.x
:: set alternateDNS=x.x.x.x

:: Change of IP address and NetMask ::
netsh interface ipv4 set address name=%connectionName% source=static addr=%ipAddress% mask=%subnetMask%


:: Change VLAN ID ::
powershell -Command "& {Set-NetAdapter -Name %ifName% -VlanID %vlanID% -Confirm:$false}"
echo The VLAN ID of %ifName% has been successfully changed to %vlanID%

pause > null
```

My batch script is running fine but I want to have only one variable for the interface name, instead of two. 
My problem is that:

If I use `ifName` in the change IP address command, I am getting the following error: `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`.

If I use the `connectionName` for the PowerShell command with double quotes, I got the following error:

```
Set-NetAdapter : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '2'.
At line:1 char:4
+ & {Set-NetAdapter -Name Ethernet 2 -VlanID 100 -Confirm:$false}
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-NetAdapter], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Set-NetAdapter
```

I have even tried to enclose the Powershell command in single quotes and use inside `connectionName` like this:

```
powershell -Command '& {Set-NetAdapter -Name %connectionName% -VlanID %vlanID% -Confirm:$false}'
```

but the network interface VLAN stays the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Set variables](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) using `set "varname=varvalue"` syntax pattern and *use them double quoted if necessary* as `echo "%varname%"`. Then, your code snippet should be as follows:

```
:: Configuration Variables
set "ifName=Ethernet 2"
set "connectionName=Ethernet 2"
set "ipAddress=10.88.167.27"
set "subnetMask=255.255.255.240"
set "vlanID=100"

:: Change of IP address and NetMask ::
netsh interface ipv4 set address name="%connectionName%" source=static addr=%ipAddress% mask=%subnetMask%

:: Change VLAN ID :: needs some tricky escaping

powershell -Command "& {Set-NetAdapter -Name """"'%connectionName%'"""" -VlanID %vlanID% -Confirm:$false}"
echo The VLAN ID of %ifName% has been successfully changed to %vlanID%
```

Comment: great tip. Just a small correction from my side, the `""""'%connectionName%'""""` needs to be changed to `'%connectionName%'` otherwise it doesn't work and I am getting the same error message.

Comment: Tested using `Write-Host` and `Write-Output` cmdlets instead of  `Set-NetAdapter` one. Both show properly single-quoted`'Ethernet 2'` for the  `""""'%connectionName%'""""` token. So I don't see any reason for failing with `Set-NetAdapter` cmdlet…